# neural network return classes instead of probabilities

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a list of 70k datas of dimension 25000 that I'm trying to feed into a neural network to get a classification of 20 different things. The system run out of memory before I can do anything. So I came out with this idea. So I divide the set of features into 5 5000. Then I feed each of the 5 set of data of dimension 5000 into a neural network. Then the result of prediction is the average of the 5.

Here is how I separated the datas:

```
datas_feature1=datas[:,0:5000]
datas_feature2=datas[:,5000:10000]
datas_feature3=datas[:,10000:15000]
datas_feature4=datas[:,15000:20000]
datas_feature5=datas[:,20000:25000]
```

Then I feed each of them into a neural network:

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(layers.Dense(300, activation = "relu", input_shape=(5000,)))
# Hidden - Layers
model1.add(layers.Dropout(0.4, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model1.add(layers.Dense(20, activation = "softmax"))
model1.summary()

model1.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model1.fit( np.array(vectorized_training1), np.array(y_train_neralnettr),
          batch_size=2000,
          epochs=10,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(np.array(vectorized_validation1), np.array(y_validation_neralnet)))
predict1= model1.predict(np.array(vectorized_validation1))
```

I have this same code for model2 neural network trained on feature2 dataset and so on. 
And in the end, I took the average of the predictions.

Here is my question: prediction from neural network gives an elementary vector and not a probability. So taking the average of the predictions is going to return a vector of 1s and 0s. How can I change so that I actually get a probability of being one of the 20 classes for each prediction?

Is my method good to try?

can you give me sone reference?

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: took too long to run actually. so I'm not sure

Comment: You have an `activation='softmax'` at the LAST layer. The output will be probability anyway.

Comment: But when you do prediction, wouldn’t it return a onehot vector instead?

Comment: No, the output of a neural network with softmax activations are probabilities, continuous values.